# MySQL joining tables WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables: Member and Member_Card. Member_Card has a column that links to Member Id column, so Member has a one to many relationship to Member_Card

I output a JSON such as:

```
{
    "Name" : "Member Name",
    "Cards": [
            { "Card_No" : "1234"},
            { "Card_No" : "4321"}
         ]
}
```

Both Member and Member_Card have a LastModifiedDate column.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Member 
LEFT JOIN Member_Card 
    ON Member_Card.Member = Member.id 
WHERE Member.LastModifiedDate >= sinceDate 
    OR Member_Card.LastModifiedDate >= sinceDate
```

The problem with this query is it will only return the Card/Member modified since sinceDate (ie if a member has 2 cards and one was modified afer sinceDate, it will just return 1 card). I want to return the member and all of its cards whether a card or the member itself were modified after sinceDate.

How could I query like that? Or do I need to run 2 queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT member.*,c.* from member inner join (
SELECT distinct member.id as  mid FROM Member 
INNER JOIN Member_Card 
    ON Member_Card.Member = Member.id 
and ( Member.LastModifiedDate >= sinceDate  
    OR Member_Card.LastModifiedDate >= sinceDate ) ) a on a.mid=member.id
inner join member_card c on c.member=a.mid
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I have hard times with queries ^^U

Comment: could you please help again? There is also the case where a member doesn't have a card, I should return the member if the date is matching http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123218/mysql-left-join-query-with-where-clause